# Can Lambda Invoke An Alexa Skill?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Is it possible for my lambda code to launch the Alexa skill and do something **without** the user saying something?

For example,

> Alexa, remind me in 10 minutes to take out the garbage

And then after 10 min my skill launches itself and says, take out the garbage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible.  It is certainly a widely requested feature though - they are very aware that developers want this.

Here's a feature request this is similar to what you are asking for.
https://forums.developer.amazon.com/content/idea/54064/push-notifications-or-reminders.html

Comment: Looks like this is coming soon: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/8cc45487-d5fb-413b-b6c7-eeea4794d10c/amazon-announces-notifications-for-alexa-feature-is-coming-soon-sign-up-to-stay-tuned